# aws lambda UTF-8 response header

Tags: amazon-web-services, utf-8, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that returns a string that contains UTF-8 characters (german umlaute). However, The AWS API-Gateway response does not contain the utf-8 header. How can I add it so the client receives a readable response?

Comment: If your client is a browser, then you should add `<meta charset="utf-8" />` to your website's HTML.

Comment: there is no actual website. I call the lambda function via the url bar (get request) and receive a json string

Comment: I'm guessing the API Gateway endpoint will be called in some kind of client. You should modify your client to correctly decode UTF8 characters. Adding a `Content-Type` header with the charset to the response would be helpful, but it won't solve anything.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  This is painfully annoying

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this problem like this in Python:

```
return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
                "content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8"},
        'body': json.dumps(data)
        }
```

I just needed to set the additional header "content-type". 
But I'm not sure whether you need to have "HTTP-Proxy-Integration" enabled (like i did).